# Unable to mock Net::OpenSSH pipe_out module in perl

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock the Net::OpenSSH pipe_out subroutine. My code is as follows

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;
use Test::Exception;
use Test::MockModule;
```

And My Begin method is

```
use_ok('Net::OpenSSH');
```

And I'm mocking the new method as follows.

```
$mockOpenSSH = Test::MockModule->new('Net::OpenSSH');
    $mockOpenSSH->mock(
        new => sub {
            my $ObjectName = shift;
            my $hostIp     = shift;
            is $hostIp, "<My IP>";
            print "Fake OpenSSH::new\n";
            return bless( {}, 'Net::OpenSSH' );
        },
    );
```

But when I try to mock the pipe_out like this

```
$mockOpenSSH->mock( 'pipe_out' => sub {return 1} );
```

I'm getting the error from my main perl module where im calling the pipe_out as

```
$ssh->pipe_out('ls');
```

Im getting the error

**#   Failed test ''
    #   at test_abc_config.t line 148.
    # died: Can't locate object method "pipe_out" via package "Test::MockModule" at abc.pm line 166.**

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: I think the problem is that you mock the `new` method and it returns an empty hash `{}` into `$ssh`. I think this will confuse the mocker, and it will forget about the `pipe_out()` method in the original `Net::OpenSSH` package..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having `new` return empty object using `bless( {}, 'Net::OpenSSH' )` you need to have `new` return a second mock object that has a `pipe_out` method, like this:

```
use Test::MockModule;
use Test::MockObject;

my $obj = Test::MockObject->new();
$obj->mock( 'pipe_out', sub { return 1 } );
$obj->set_isa('Net::OpenSSH');

$mockOpenSSH = Test::MockModule->new('Net::OpenSSH');
    $mockOpenSSH->mock(
        new => sub {
            my $ObjectName = shift;
            my $hostIp     = shift;
            is $hostIp, "<My IP>";
            print "Fake OpenSSH::new\n";
            return $obj;
        },
    );
```

Read more about [Test::MockObject](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockObject).